# Add Vue 3 with Laravel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-8

I am trying to install VueJS with Laravel.  My `app.js` file is like below.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
window.Vue = Vue;
require('./bootstrap'); 

Vue.component('mosque-component', require('./components/MosqueComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('prayer-component', require('./components/PrayerComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('time-component', require('./components/TimeComponent.vue').default);


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#content',
});
```

I attached VueJS component like below.

```
@section('content')
    <div>
        <mosque-component />
    </div>
@endsection
```

I added `app.js` file like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

My `package.json` file is like below.

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.56.2",
        "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
        "vue-loader": "^16.8.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "^3.2.45"
    }
}
```

I am getting error like this `Uncaught TypeError: vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default is undefined`.

[image]

Comment: did you setup laravel mix ? Also you are mixing Vue 2 syntax with a Vue 3 install, see : https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html for a valid syntax for your app.js

Comment: Thanks @Lk77. I am using VueJS with Laravel. Yes, I am using Laravel mix. How can I fix the error ?

Comment: You need to use Vue3 syntax, you should not have something like `new Vue`, but more something like `Vue.createApp` or simply `createApp` if you import that function. Same goes for `Vue.component`, you need to replace with `app.component`, after doing something like `const app = createApp(...)`. You also need to call the mount function like so `app.mount('#app')`. Look for tutorials online